# Create table columns dynamically in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I'm working on dashboard application where I have to retrieve a set of records and display in dynamic tables boxes. Page frame length is fixed. now of columns and rows can be initialized. It should look like this sample:

[image]

Currently I'm using data table to display but it prints all the data in one column. How would I change my code to above pattern?

```
<o:dataTable id="tabBlSearch" var="item"
     onkeyup="handleLeftRightArrowOnDataTable('frmDashBoard:tabBlSearch')"
     value="#{bLDashBoardAction.listBondLoc}">
  <o:column style="width: 20px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.awb}" />
  </o:column>
</o:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this with standard JSF components using a `<h:panelGrid>` wherein `<c:forEach>` is been used to generate the cells during the view build time. The `<ui:repeat>` won't work as that runs during view render time.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="5">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

As to component libraries, I don't see anything in [OpenFaces' showcase](http://www.openfaces.org/components/), but PrimeFaces has a [`<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf) for exactly this purpose, even with pagination support.

```
<p:dataGrid columns="5" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```