# Display a list of images in a table format in JSF

Tags: image, jsf, repeat

This is probably a really simple JSF question, but I can't seem to find the simple answer.

I have a List of images, and I want to display them in a table of images. Each image is displayed with its filename. I'm using a `ui:repeat` tag as shown below. I don't get 5 columns as requested, however, only 1.

```
<h:panelGrid id="resourcePanel" columns="5" rules="all">
    <ui:repeat var="res" value="#{resourceUpload.resources}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" rules="none">
                <h:graphicImage
                    value="/image/resource?id=#{res.idAsString}"
                    style="width:100px;" />
                <h:outputText value="#{res.name}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is fully as expected and specified. The `<ui:repeat>` is a render time tag, not a view build time tag like `<c:forEach>`. After building the view, `<h:panelGrid>` ends up with 1 child component (the `<ui:repeat>` itself), not with *n* nested `<h:panelGrid>` components like as you would get with `<c:forEach>`.

```
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
...
<h:panelGrid id="resourcePanel" columns="5" rules="all">
    <c:forEach var="res" items="#{resourceUpload.resources}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" rules="none">
            <h:graphicImage
                value="/image/resource?id=#{res.idAsString}"
                style="width:100px;" />
            <h:outputText value="#{res.name}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

*(this has in the Mojarra versions older than 2.1.18 however an implication on `#{resourceUpload}`: it can't be a view scoped bean, it must be request scoped due to a chicken-egg issue in view state saving/restoring; you'd need to upgrade to Mojarra 2.1.18)*

Your nested `<h:panelGrid>` makes by the way no utter sense. I'd have used `<h:panelGroup>` here.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) - to understand "view build time" vs "view render time" better
- [create table columns dynamically in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280688/create-table-columns-dynamically-in-jsf) - another similar question

Comment: Thanks - looks like good info - I'll look into view render time vs view build time

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use another `<h:panelGrid>` inside the `<ui:repeat>`? You can just use a div like this.
Instead of

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" rules="none">
```

use

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
```

Edit:

---

I don't think that you can do it with `<ui:repeat>`. Use `<c:forEach>` instead.

First you should import the namespace

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

Now replace the `<ui:repeat>` with `<c:forEach>` like this.

```
<c:forEach items="#{accountMastList.resultList}" var="res">
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'll have to look into div - I've never used that tag before

Comment: Actually, this only sort of works. I don't have 6 columns - it basically spans the page. Which might be ok, but I'd also like the option to set the number of columns. Can that be done with the div inline-block tag?

Comment: Change the `columns` attribute of main `panelGrid` like this. `<h:panelGrid id="resourcePanel" columns="#{resourceUpload.resources.size()}" rules="all">`.

Comment: No - I don't want to set the number of columns to the size of the resource list. It could have dozens or even hundreds of items. I want to set it to a specific size (say 6), but anything I do on that external panelGrid does not seem to affect the ui:repeat