# Values displaying in a single column even if columns attribute is set to 2 in <h:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using a  to print in two strings in two columns as in the following code:

```
<h:panelGrid
            columns="2" border="1">
        <ui:repeat
            value="#{bean.selectedLocales}"
                    var="locale">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg[locale]}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The above prints two locales **en** and **de** taken from a list in a *same* column although I use `ui:repeat` and `columns="2"` in `<h:panelGrid>`. How can I make it to print in two different columns?

Comment: @Daniel - Nope, not working!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945544/uirepeat-and-hpanelgrid

Comment: @cubbuk - The above solution is displaying it in 2 rows instead of 2 columns!

Comment: You can replace ui:repeat with c:forEach, but this might create problem later on when the number of selectedLocales change dynamically. Otherwise you might wanna check the following article http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDynamicDatatable

Comment: possible duplicate of [create table columns dynamically in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280688/create-table-columns-dynamically-in-jsf)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your `h:panelGrid` contains only one nested element: `ui:repeat`, and it cannot show the one element in two columns.
What about doing a dynamic dataTable of it using the vendor specific `columns` eg. `p:columns`, `ice:columns` in the JSF page and `javax.faces.model.ListDataModel` in the managed bean?

Comment: Thanks! But the above solution is displaying it in 2 rows instead of 2 columns. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `ListDataModel` in the managed bean when using with `h:dataTable`?

Comment: I don't see other solution if you want to show a non-constant number of columns in a dataTable.

Comment: Is it not possible with a simple `List` of items?

Comment: If I use anything in the <h:column>, the list of values are displayed in new rows in the same column. But how do I display each item of a list is separate columns?

Comment: `h:columns` [doesn't exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).